# using if count in the part of the sql statement

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    messages
WHERE
       (messages.to = 'Jack' AND (type = 'message' OR type = 'reply'))
    OR (messages.from = 'Jack' AND type = 'reply')
    OR (messages.from = 'Jack' AND type = 'message')
ORDER BY messages.message_id DESC , messages.id DESC
```

I want to filter out the results in the last query statement where it says

```
(messages.from='Jack' AND type='message')
```

if the count of it equals 1.

Comment: The count of what? The conditions in the where clause apply to a single record, so 'its' count is always 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using subquery, i would have done something like this in place of last condition :

```
messages.from = 'Jack' AND 
type = 'message' AND 
1 =(select count(primary_key) from messages /* 1=count : this would ensure that 
                                               condition works only if 
                                               1 row is returned*/
where (messages.from='Jack' AND type='message')  )
```

So final SQL would have been :

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    messages
WHERE
       (messages.to = 'Jack' AND (type = 'message' OR type = 'reply'))
    OR (messages.from = 'Jack' AND type = 'reply')
    OR (messages.from = 'Jack' AND 
        type = 'message' AND 
        1 =(select count(primary_key) from messages
        where (messages.from='Jack' AND type='message')  ))

        ORDER BY messages.message_id DESC , messages.id DESC
```

Comment: what is the meaning of count(primary_key)

Comment: `count(primary_key)` is just for demo, replace it with the attribute which is `primary_key` in your table....this way, it would count the number of rows returned and compare it with `1`

Comment: I am having multiple messages with the same id´s (like a questions and answers). In your case is the query counting all the messages in the table and not per message_id. I need the count per message_id in order to get a list per id with this count that not equals 1.

Comment: in that case, you can `select` using `distinct` :)

Comment: You mean in the subquery

Comment: yes...see,in case of multiple message id, use `count(message_id)`...this will be more than 1 if u have multiple message id's...

Comment: i have tried with the following  but I am not getting the desired result: it is still showing the id´s whose count is 1. 1<(select DISTINCT count(message_id) from messages
    where (messages.from='Jack' AND type='message') ))
    ORDER BY messages.message_id DESC , messages.id DESC";

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47855/discussion-between-noobeditor-and-user2615859)

Comment: @user2615859 : please use above link to come on chat :)